# Setup timed events in WPF

Tags: wpf, timer

How can I setup events that happen after a certain period of time. Like saving changes every 30 seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a timer and fire them that way.